# What is the best way insert/update data to the database

Tags: c#, sql, database, performance

Given that we have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE TestData 
(
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Value INT
)
```

When writing data to the table, I will try to `UPDATE` the table if the ID already exists or else `INSERT` a new row.

There are several options that I've written or come across in production code:

1. Perform an `UPDATE` query first, if no row is updated, perform an `INSERT` query
2. Perform an `Insert` query first first, if it fails, performs an `INSERT` query
3. Perform a `SELECT` query with new ID  first, then if the row exists do `UPDATE` else `INSERT` query
4. Perform one big query to do all select update or insert

My question is what is the `best practice` or `most efficient` or `preferred method` amongst the above options (or your own method)?

Example code for above options:

(1) Perform an `UPDATE` query first, if no row is updated, perform an `INSERT` query

```
int affectedRows = 0;
using (IDbCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TestData SET Value = @Value WHERE ID = @ID", myConn))
{
    try
    {
        // ...add params
        affectedRows = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException) { /*...*/ }
}

if (affectedRows == 0)
{
    using (IDbCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (@ID, @Value)", myConn))
    {
        try
        {
            // ...add params
            affectedRows = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException) { /*...*/ }
    }
}
```

(2) Perform an `Insert` query first first, if it fails, performs an `INSERT` query

```
int affectedRows = 0;
using (IDbCommand insertCmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (@ID, @Value)", myConn))
{
    try
    {
        // ... add params
        affectedRows = insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException) { /*...*/ }
}

if (affectedRows == 0)
{
    using (IDbCommand updateCmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE TestData SET Value = @Value WHERE ID = @ID", myConn))
    {
        try
        {
            // ...add params
            affectedRows = updateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException) { /*...*/ }
    }
}
```

(3) Perform a `SELECT` query with new ID  first, then if the row exists do `UPDATE` else `INSERT` query

```
bool dataExist = false;
// ... 
using (IDbCommand selectCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM TestDate WHERE ID=@ID", myConn))
{
    try
    {
        // ... add param
        using (IDataReader reader = selectCmd.ExecuteReader())
            dataExist = reader.Read();
    }
    catch (SqlException) { /*...*/ }
}
if (dataExist) { /* update query, similar to above one*/ }
else { /* insert, similar to above one */ }
```

(4) Perform one big query to do all select update or insert

```
string query = "IF EXISTS (SELECT ID FROM TestData WHERE ID=@ID) " +
               "UPDATE TestData SET Value = @Value WHERE ID = @ID " +
               "ELSE INSERT INTO TestData VALUES (@ID, @Value)";

using (IDbCommand bigQueryCmd = new SqlCommand(query, myConn))
{
    try
    {
        // ... add param
        bigQueryCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (SqlException) { /*...*/ }
}
```

Comment: Check if you can use `MERGE`

Comment: For me..NONE as your code is very much prone to SQL Injection! And if you overcome with it then you can instead create a stored procedure and create your update and insert logic in there.

Comment: @lad2025 This is a straight insert new data into the table. Where should I `MERGE` from?

Comment: MERGE with derived table

Answer (score 0):

You could use **[MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)**.

> Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based
>   on the results of a join with a source table.

For concurrency reasons it is much better to use **`MERGE`** than `IF EXISTS/UPDATE/INSERT` and it is only one statement so less code to maintain:

Something like:

**[SqlFiddleDemo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d310/2/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE TestData (
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Value INT);

INSERT INTO TestData
VALUES (1,3);


DECLARE @id INT = 1, @value INT = 10;    -- will update
--DECLARE @id INT = 2, @value INT = 10;  -- will insert

;MERGE TestData AS TGT
USING (SELECT * FROM (SELECT @id AS ID, @value AS VALUE) AS t) AS SRC
   ON TGT.ID = SRC.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN
   UPDATE SET Value = SRC.[VALUE]
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
   INSERT (ID, [VALUE])
   VALUES (SRC.ID, SRC.[VALUE]);

SELECT *
FROM TestData;
```

Comment: Is this one big query to be called from C#?

Comment: Yes, you need to bind parameters, and it should work. But first check using SSMS

Comment: I know MERGE would work, the question is if it is a better approach then others. I found it very similar to the 4th option IF EXISTS / UPDATE / INSERT)

Comment: @VietNguyen MERGE is one statement only, done with implicit transactions. What if you have concurrent application and you use your multipart IF EXISTS/UPDATE/INSERT. One query can check for exists when another will insert data